# Trouble with table borders

Tags: tables

I want my table to look like the one below:
[image]

But this is what is turning out:
[image]

Here’s an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Treatment Received}\\ \cline{2-3}
& All Respondents & Prejudiced Respondents\\ \hline
Culturally Foreign &    25.6 & 44.4\\ 
Culturally Familiar & 20.0 & 19.0\\
Difference & 5.6 & 25.4*\\
(95\% Confidence Interval) & (-1.1 to 12.4) & (6.6 to 44.1)\\
p-value & 0.101  & 0.009\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're forgetting a `|` in the argument to `\multicolumn` and have a useless `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`; when a cell is empty, just place nothing in it.

The first column should be left aligned. I also propose a different way to format the table, without any vertical rule (this second way requires `booktabs`). Also I wouldn't use `\doublespace`, you just lose in readability.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Treatment Received}\\
\cline{2-3}
  & All Respondents & Prejudiced Respondents\\
\hline
  Culturally Foreign  & $25.6$ & $44.4$\\ 
  Culturally Familiar & $20.0$ & $19.0$\\
  Difference          &  $5.6$ & $25.4$\makebox[0pt][l]{*}\\
  ($95$\% Confidence Interval) & ($-1.1$ to $12.4$) & ($6.6$ to $44.1$)\\
  $p$-value           & $0.101$  & $0.009$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Treatment Received}\\
\cmidrule{2-3}
  & All Respondents & Prejudiced Respondents\\
\midrule
  Culturally Foreign  & $25.6$ & $44.4$\\ 
  Culturally Familiar & $20.0$ & $19.0$\\
  Difference          &  $5.6$ & $25.4$\makebox[0pt][l]{*}\\
  ($95$\% Confidence Interval) & ($-1.1$ to $12.4$) & ($6.6$ to $44.1$)\\
  $p$-value           & $0.101$  & $0.009$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also how I typed the asterisk, so that it doesn't participate in the alignment. Also, numbers should be typed in math mode, particularly if they are negative.

Comment: +1 for using `booktabs`

Comment: @alexwlchan I *always* use it and *never* use `\multirow`. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

When you define the alignment for the uses of `\multicolumn` (this is the `{c}`), you need to tell it what vertical borders you want around them (just like when you write `{|c|c|c|}` at the begin of the table).

So replace the line

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Treatment Received}\\ \cline{2-3}
```

with

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Treatment Received}\\ \cline{2-3}
```

Notice that `{c}` has become `{|c}` and `{c|}`.

This is what the result looks like:

[image]